# Xamarin Forms Android - Timer should run when display is turned off

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have programmed an app in Xamarin Forms for Android which has a timer and this timer should also run when the app is closed and the display is turned off.
The problem: When the display is closed then the timer does not run anymore.
When only the app is closed there is no problem.
How can I fix this?
Thanks a lot

Here is my Code:

```
public void StartCountdown()
    {    
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

        if (cancel == true)
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
        }

        task = Task.Run(async () =>
       {
               Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
               {
                   restTime -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                   if (cancel == true)
                   {
                       return false;
                   }
                   if (restTime == zero)
                   {
                       StartDownload();
                       return false; 
                    }
                   else
                   {
                       Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                       {
                           ActivateElements(false);
                       });

                       return true;                       }
               });
           
       }, token);
    }
```

Comment: You will need to implement an Android Foreground Service that contains your timer code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

Comment: Hi SushiHangover is maybe Background Service better for my app? What you mean ? Thank you

Comment: I agree that Background Service is what you need. HOWEVER, why does the timer need to run while display is off? What will you do when the timer finishes? Display off means you should minimize your use of resources. Is there an alternative design, where you note the time when display goes off (app going to background), then when app returns to foreground, check how much time has passed, add that to timer. Be aware that the USER should have final control, not your app. Or perhaps have the timer completion send a notification. That alerts user, without fully waking up the app.

Comment: Hello ToolmakerSteve,

Thank you very much for the detailed answer:
Here are the answers for your questions:
1. however, why does the timer need to run while the display is off - Because the timer should run independently of display.
2. what are you going to do when the timer runs out? - The Wi-Fi will be turned off.
3. or let the timer completion send a notification. - Rather no notification comes when the timer expires. 

Just as I read on the internet as of Android Oreo a background service is simply killed at resource scarcity. That would be really big disadvantage for me.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? Background or foreground which one did fix your problem?